# Inserting Chatter FeedItems with type 'TrackedChange'

Tags: chatter, data-loader, chatter-feed, data-migration

I am trying to insert a Chatter FeedItem through Data Loader. When the type is 'TrackedChange', I am getting the error

> 'Cannot directly insert FeedItem with type 'TrackedChange'.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Tracked changes are for field history tracking chatter feeds thus they maintain audit logs and thus wount be allowed to be inserted by SF to maintain integrity of data.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to insert a `FeedItem` with *Type* `TrackedChange`.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) states that you cannot create a `FeedItem` with all `Type` values, but only few. Below is an excerpt from the `Type` field's description:

> The type of FeedItem. Except for ContentPost, LinkPost, and TextPost, don’t create FeedItem types directly from the API.

A `FeedItem` with *Type* `TrackedChange` will be automatically created if there are fields available in the feed item for the Object, for which the feed was generated, being tracked as part of audit history. This will also indirectly create the `FeedTrackedChange` record capturing the field changes.

> TrackedChange — a change or group of changes to a tracked field.

Furthermore, [FeedTrackedChange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedtrackedchange.htm#topic-title) object itself is not *creatable* from APIs.